# Copying lines matching pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have been trying to look for a certain command in forums for some time and did not find the solution so I hope you will be able to help me. What I'm trying to do is fairly simple. I want to duplicate lines that match a pattern using see. For instance, if I have a file that looks like:

```
abc
def
cda
abd
```

I would like to duplicate every line that contains 'ab', i.e.:

```
abc
abc
def
cda
abd
abd
```

I have tried the following syntax:

```
sed '/ab/a\&' myfile
```

cause I've read somewhere that the character "&" stands for the pattern that has been matched but all I get is:

```
abc
&def
cda
abd
&
```

Is there anything I'm missing. I guess there is.

Thanks a lot for any help.

FYI, I'm using mac OS X

Comment: `&` is only special in the replacement part of the `s///` command.

Comment: `&` is not only in `s///` but mean *the whole search pattern content*. So in `s/ab/` it is `ab`, in `s/.*ab.*/` it is the whole line containing `ab`. `s///` only work if there is a precedent search pattern occuring, like in `/ab/p` or `s/ab/foo/`, and taking this search pattern as current search pattern (here is is equivalent to `s/ab//`

Answer (score 6):

It can be extremely simple:

```
sed '/ab/p' file
```

sed prints each line by default. For matching lines, print the line an extra time.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below.

```
$ sed 's/.*ab.*/&\n&/g' file
abc
abc
def
cda
abd
abd
```

Answer (score 1):

A short `awk` version:

```
awk '/ab/;1' file
abc
abc
def
cda
abd
abd
```